# AppConKit3: My changes in the Java Server files get overriden

Tags: java, appconkit

I'm playing with the AppConKit, and have created a small App so far with a couple of screens. Now I am trying to change the automatically generate Java code. However, any changes I make in the automatically Action classes (for example LoadDetailAction.java) get overwritten every time I change something in the UI. Any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, updated it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of each generated class, there is a JavaDoc comment which looks like this:

```
/**
 * @generated
 */
public class LoadDataAction {
```

Just remove the @generated from the JavaDoc comment and the class won't be overwritten anymore.